# Validator in spring MVC without configuration message properties file

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I have scenario like that.

*1. I have jsp file, there are two field: toDate and fromDate:*

```
<form:form id="testForm" modelAttribute="testForm" action="testAction">
    Name: <form:input path="name" />
    From date: <form:input path="fromDate" id="fromDate" />
    <form:errors path="fromDate" class="control-label" />
    To date: <form:input path="toDate" id="toDate" />
    <input id="mySubmitButton" type="submit" value="HELLO">
</form:form>
```

*2. I have a Controller to handle request from my page as below:*

```
@Autowired
   TestFormValidator validator;

@InitBinder
protected void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
    binder.setValidator(validator);
}
@RequestMapping(value = "/testAction", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String doSomeThing(ModelMap model,
        @ModelAttribute @Validated TestForm testForm, BindingResult result,
        RedirectAttributes redirectAttrs) {
    if (result != null && result.hasErrors()) {
        return "hello";
    }
```

*3. I have Validator class to validate the TestForm:*

```
@Component
public class TestFormValidator implements Validator {

@Override
public boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {
    return TestForm.class.equals(clazz);
}

@Override
public void validate(Object arg0, Errors errors) {
    TestForm testForm = (TestForm) arg0;
    if (testForm.getFromDate() != null
            && testForm.getFromDate().after(testForm.toDate)) {
        errors.rejectValue("fromDate", "From date must not be after to date.");
    }

}
```

*4. Yep, the following code is correct what I want. But I always meet the Exception:*

org.springframework.context.NoSuchMessageException: No message found under code 'From date must not be after to date..testForm.fromDate' for locale...

*5. I know that I miss declaration the bean:* **messageSource**

**My question:**

I question whether are there any methods to return an error message without declaring message properties file?

**Thanks in advance!!!**

Answer (score 4):

You can try [Errors.rejectValue(String field,
                 String errorCode,
                 String defaultMessage)](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/Errors.html#rejectValue-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) method. So your code must change as following.

```
errors.rejectValue("fromDate", "error.invalidFromDate", "From date must not be after to date.");
```

This should ideal use the defaultMessage in the scenario where it can't find the error code from message source.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this alternative..
The error message can be specified in the validation annotation, for example:
@NotEmpty(message = "Please enter your email addresss.")
private String email;

And for integer values
@NotNull(message = "...".)
Private Integer contactNumber

By doing this u can display error messages on your jsp page